# Fixed effects model with explanatory variable that is a function of a fixed effect-level observable

Tags: interpretation, fixed-effects-model

I have a question about the interpretation of parameters in a fixed effect specification, sorry that the context is a bit specific.

In the data/working paper that I am looking at, there are a number of ideas $i$ which are evaluated by a number of evaluators $j$. Each idea is proposed by someone who has a hierarchy in a firm $H_i$. Each evaluator has hierarchy $H_j$. The people who proposed and the people who evaluate the ideas are within the same company and each $j$ evaluates every $i$.

Now, the idea is to evaluate the effect that the difference in the hierarchy level has on the evaluation score. One of the specifications that was proposed is essentially:

$Y_{ij} = \alpha_i + \beta (H_i - H_j) + \epsilon_{ij}$

However, if you estimate that by demeaning the regression variables, the part behind $\beta$ becomes $\bar{H_j} - H_j$, which is what is actually being estimated.

So, by including these fixed effects, would one estimate a parameter $\beta$, whose interpretation is simultaneously that the hierarchical distance increases and that the distance from the mean evaluator increases? (Because obviously, if you run the regression with the second thing as the observable, you get the same coefficient because demeaning something demeaned doesn't change anything) In terms of the underlying theory, both things would be interesting but something very different.

I found that a bit puzzling, maybe there is someone who can set my thinking straight.

(They also add a squared term, which would then become $-2 H_i (H_j - \bar{H_j}) + (H_j^2 - \bar{H_j^2})$. For that I don't see an immediate interpretation, but it is certainly also something else)